# Fix Page Layout in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I am creating Mail Merge using Google Docs and Sheets with App Script, send email with PDF attachment. Everything is working fine with App Script.

But google docs layout keep changing depending on length of the replaced values. I have Project Title as placeholder in two places

Title1: EMOTION RECOGNITION BY TEXTUAL TWEETS CLASSIFICATION USING VOTING CLASSIFIER (LR-SGD)
Title2: VOTING CLASSIFIER

If I use Title2, it is working fine but for Title1, text is shifting to next page although there is enough space for title.

Need help to fix the page layout. It should not change based on text length.

Thank You.

Comment: It seems that this is a limitations/issues of Mail merge, I have seen an article/thread: [mail merge loses template letterhead](https://groups.google.com/g/mail-merge-documents/c/PCzuCXSCUaY) with almost the same problem as yours. Have you considered changing /adjusting the document's margins and font size?